# Listing all shell types used by users

Tags: command-line, users

I am looking for a way to list all sessions, something like the command who, that would also list the type of shell being used by the list of users.

Comment: What about extracting the login shell information from `/etc/passwd`?

Comment: `sudo ps -ef | egrep 'tty|pts'` might give you an idea.

Comment: What do you mean by shell *type*? Like C-shell or Bourne shell family (type)?

Comment: I assume you mean shell name, not shell type. If you mean type, please [edit] your question and clarify what a shell's "type" is. Do you mean login, non-login, interactive etc? Do you mean family of shells as heemayl suggested?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what you want, you can use `who`'s cousin `w`:

```
$ w
 17:40:49 up 11 days, 22:38,  4 users,  load average: 0.14, 0.13, 0.10
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
muru     tty7     :0               12Jan17 11days  2:24m  0.37s /sbin/upstart --user
muru     pts/24   127.0.0.1:S.0    17:36    0.00s  0.41s  0.00s w
muru     pts/26   127.0.0.1:S.2    17:38    2:33   0.19s  0.19s -/bin/zsh
```

It runs the active command on the login terminal. You can use the terminal ID to see which shell I started originally:

```
$ w -h | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -L1 pgrep -oat
1969 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
12703 -/bin/zsh
13398 -/bin/zsh
```

`pgrep` can:

- match using a terminal (`-t`)
- print the oldest matching process (`-o`)
- print the whole command line (`-a`)

Comment: The w command is exactly what I needed thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here's a script  which lists the PID of a shell, its binary, the terminal to which the shell's stdin is attached, and username of the process owner.The script makes extensive use of `/proc` filesystem for better accuracy.

What you see in the screenshot below is sample run of that script. I have two splits open with Terminator terminal emulator. The number in square brackets of each prompt is the PID of that shell. The top split confirms that I have two `mksh` instances open in  virtual pseudo-terminals, which is GUI terminals, and one bash instance. Another `mksh` instance can be found in `tty1`. What's also interesting is there are two `dash` instances, attached to `/dev/null`. Upon examining the processes to which they belong, it turns out those belong to one Unity appindicator and zeitgeist service. Thus , in this script it is easier to see which shells are actually being used by real users, and which by system processes.

[image]

The script source is below and also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/SergKolo/sergrep/blob/master/find_open_shells.sh)

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

is_self(){

    if [ "$link" == "/bin/bash" ] &&  grep -q $0 /proc/$proc_pid/cmdline
    then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi

}
print_proc_info(){
     terminal=$( readlink -e "/proc/$proc_pid/fd/0" )
     [ -z "$terminal"  ] && terminal=$'\t'
     printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t" "$proc_pid" "$1" "$terminal"
     stat --printf="%U\n" /proc/"$proc_pid"/mountstats 
}

find_process(){
     local function_pid=$$

     local search_base=$(basename "$1")

     find /proc -maxdepth 1 -type d -path "*/[1-9]*" | while read -r proc_dir;
     do
         local proc_pid=$(basename "$proc_dir")
         local link=$(readlink -e "$proc_dir"/exe)
         local name=$( awk 'NR==1{print $2}' "$proc_dir"/status  2>/dev/null )

         if is_self ; then continue ; fi

         if [ "$link" == "$1"   ] ||
            [ -z "$link"  ] && [ "$name" = "$search_base"  ]
         then
             print_proc_info $1
         # make additional check if readlink wasn't allowed to 
         # get where /proc/[pid]/exe is symlinked

         fi
     done

}

main(){
    while read -r shell
    do
        find_process "$shell" 
    done < /etc/shells 

    echo "Done, press [ENTER] to continue"
    read
}

main
```

Answer (score 1):

Since all installed shells on your system are listed in `/etc/shells`, you can start from there and use `ps` to list which ones are running and associated information.

So, first, get the list of shells:

```
$ grep -oP '^/.*/\K.*' /etc/shells | sort -u
bash
csh
dash
fish
ksh
mksh
sh
tcsh
zsh
```

The `-o` means "print only the matching part of the line" and the `-P` enables PCRE, Perl Compatible Regular Expressions, which let us use fancy things like `\K`, which means "ignore everything matched up to this point". So, `^/.*/\K.*` means match lines starting with a `/` (`^/`), then as many characters as possible until a `/` (`.*/`), then forget about what was matched so far (`\K`) and match everything else until the end of the line. This will effectively return the last part of each line, the actual name of the shell (e.g. `bash` for `/bin/bash`).

The `sort -u` just ensures no shells are printed twice (sometimes you can have the same shell in both `/bin` and `/usr/bin`).

But, we want to use this list for searching the output of `ps`, so we need it in a format that `grep` can understand:

```
$ grep -oP '^/.*/\K.*' /etc/shells | sort -u | perl -pe '!eof && s/\n/\|/'
bash|csh|dash|fish|ksh|mksh|sh|tcsh|zsh
```

That `perl` command just replaces newline characters (`\n`) with `|`, so this can be fed directly to `grep`.

We now use `pgrep` to list all matching processes:

```
$ pgrep -x "$(grep -oP '^/.*/\K.*' /etc/shells | sort -u | 
    perl -pe '!eof && s/\n/\|/')" 
1235
5399
14031
14116
14200
14304
14337
14392
15257
15368
15551
15601
15704
15877
17033
28177
29138
30797
32404
32656
```

The `-x` is needed so that only processes that match exactly (so no `foosh` for `sh`).

Now that we have the list of target PIDs, we can pass them to `ps` and use it to print the relevant information:

```
$ pgrep -x "$(grep -oP '^/.*/\K.*' /etc/shells | sort -u | 
    perl -pe '!eof && s/\n/\|/')" | 
        while read pid; do ps -p $pid -o pid=,cmd=,euser=,tty=; done
 1235 /bin/bash                   terdon   pts/1
 5399 /bin/bash                   terdon   pts/4
12341 /bin/bash                   terdon   pts/2
14031 /bin/bash                   terdon   pts/8
14116 /bin/bash                   terdon   pts/9
14200 /bin/bash                   terdon   pts/10
14304 /bin/bash                   terdon   pts/11
14337 /bin/bash                   terdon   pts/12
14392 /bin/bash                   terdon   pts/13
15257 dash                        terdon   pts/13
15368 zsh                         terdon   pts/12
15551 mksh                        terdon   pts/11
15601 -sh                         terdon   pts/10
15704 -csh                        terdon   pts/9
15877 sh                          terdon   pts/8
17033 /bin/bash                   terdon   pts/2
28177 /bin/bash                   terdon   pts/3
29138 fish                        terdon   pts/3
30797 /bin/bash                   terdon   pts/5
32404 /bin/bash                   terdon   pts/6
32656 /bin/bash                   terdon   pts/7
```

This reads each PID produced by the previous steps and runs `ps` for it (`-p $pid`), using the `-o` flag to control output to print the PID, the command used, the user who launched it and the terminal device it is attached to.

Answer (score 1):

Shell information with child processes

```
ps -efH | egrep 'pts/|tty'

sup      14536  2065  0 17:05 pts/19   00:00:00               bash
sup      14572 14536  0 17:05 pts/19   00:00:00                 dash
sup      14575 14572  0 17:05 pts/19   00:00:00                   bash
sup      14611 14575  0 17:05 pts/19   00:00:00                     dash
sup      14673  1956  0 17:06 pts/6    00:00:00             /bin/bash
sup      14717 14673  0 17:06 pts/6    00:00:00               bash
sup      15650 14717  0 17:16 pts/6    00:00:00                 ps -efH
```